# Why does change my mix-manifest file when i run npm run dev code?

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When i run this code `npm run dev` in my Laravel+Vue.js project it changing my ***mix-manifest.json*** file. I dont want this. What can i do?

I want to add static values to mix-manifest.json or dynamic values.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't edit this file. It is automatically regenerated when you run npm run dev. Think about other solution.